# Javolution - How do I filter a FastTable using Predicate?

Tags: java, javolution

I am trying to obtain a filtered subset of a Javolution FastTable, using a Predicate.
When running my code, execution never gets past this line:

```
FastTable<UUID> chunksToRender = 
    (FastTable <UUID>)ChunkManager.getInstance().chunkBuffer.filtered(
        new Predicate<UUID>()
        {
            public boolean test(UUID id)
            {
                return ChunkStore.getInstance().getChunk( id ).blocksLoaded();
            }
        });
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?